# Pause html video that's on autoplay?

Tags: javascript

Thought it might be easier if I linked to some (partly) working code
http://jsfiddle.net/StephenMeehan80/mfjtaco3/6/

The video autoplay is controlled by Javascript, and the pause/play button "works", but it needs to to be clicked twice the first time?

Is there a way to add `videoAutoPlay` into the `EventListener`?

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {

            var video = document.getElementById('videoContent');
            videoAutoPlay = video.play();

            document.getElementById("playVideo").addEventListener("click", function(){              
                
                if(this.className == 'is-playing')
                {
                    this.className = "";
                    this.innerHTML = "Play"
                    video.pause();
                }
                else{
                    this.className = "is-playing";
                    this.innerHTML = "Pause";
                    video.play();
                }
            });
        });



    <button id="playVideo">Pause</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not working because `className is not a valid property. Use Element.classList.toggle:

```
var video = document.getElementById('videoContent');
videoAutoPlay = video.play();

document.getElementById("playVideo").addEventListener("click", function(){     
   this.classList.toggle('is-playing');     
   if(this.classList.contains('is-playing')) {
       this.innerHTML = "Play"
       video.pause();
   } else {
       this.innerHTML = "Pause";
       video.play();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I've mostly got it working now. Would you mind taking a look at my updated answer? With a link to the fiddle.

Comment: Works! Many thanks. I've updated the fiddle in case it's useful for anyone else
http://jsfiddle.net/StephenMeehan80/mfjtaco3/11/

Comment: Yes, this can help others ;)

Answer (score 0):

on button click set videoPlaying to false. And your if else statement looks wrong.
You have if videoPlaying is true do something.
Else if videoPlaying is false put videoPlaying to false.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
            document.getElementById("playVideo").addEventListener("click", function(){
                
                var videoPlaying = true;
                var video = document.getElementById('videoContent');
                
                    if(videoPlaying)
                    {
                        
                        this.innerHTML = "Play"
                        video.play();                  
                    }
                    else{
                        this.innerHTML = "Pause";
                        video.pause();
                }
            });
        });
 const pauseResume = () => {
if(videoPlaying){
videoPlaying == false
}else{
videoPlaying == true
}

<button onclick= pauseResume()>pause/resume</button>
```

It should looks something like that.

Comment: Cheers, I've updated my question. I've nearly got this working. Would you mind taking a look at the JS Fiddle?